# How to run multiple workflows at same time on Github

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm having a little trouble setting up the workflow for github using the actions. Actually the workflow are running when an workflow are triggered (by a commit specificly), but there is a problem, if i change the code and commit it to a new pull request, and someone else commit another change for another pull request, my workflow will run, but the second worflow will wait the first finish, and it takes a long time to can be started.

I searched a lot for the documentation of actions to see if i find something to do, but there is a lot of multiple jobs documentation (who i already have on my workflow), but anything talking about to run simultaneous workflows.

Is important to say, i'm using self-hosted runner, if that impacts something.

my actual workflow setting is:

```
name: CI

on: [workflow_dispatch, push]

jobs:
  rspec:
    name: RSpec
    runs-on: self-hosted
    container:
      image: ruby:3.1.3
    env:
      RAILS_ENV: test
      BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
      DB_HOST: mysql

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        env:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb_test
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: {PASSWORD}
          MYSQL_USER: {ADMIN_USER}
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: {PASSWORD}
        ports:
          - 3306
      redis:
        image: redis:alpine
        ports: ["6379:6379"]
        options: --entrypoint redis-server

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Allow use of sudo
        run: |
          apt-get update && apt-get -y install sudo
          sudo apt-get update

      - name: Install depencies
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-doc libidn11-dev libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev librtmp-dev libssh2-1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.13.0
          cache: 'npm'

      - name: Install node dependencies
        run: npm install --legacy-peer-deps

      - name: Install gems
        run: bundle install

      - name: Create Log folder and default files
        run: mkdir log && touch log/sidekiq.log && touch log/whenever.log

      - name: Create database
        run: |
          cp config/database/database.yml.development config/database.yml
          bundle exec rails db:schema:load

      - name: Build vite
        run: bin/vite build

      - name: Run tests
        env: 
          RAILS_ENV: test
          CI: true
          SLOWS: true
          COVERAGE: true
        run: bundle exec rspec spec

      - name: Archive code coverage results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: code-coverage-report
          path: ./coverage/
          retention-days: 7`
```

I don't find anything about that, so i only try to search something about it

Comment: _but the second workflow will wait the first to finish_: According to the workflow implementation you shared, two workflow runs should be able to run simultaneously receiving 2 different events that trigger it at the same time. It may be related to your self-hosted runner capacity, did you check the [autoscaling configurations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/autoscaling-with-self-hosted-runners) for self-hosted runners?

Comment: Workflow runs will run independent of each other unless you have defined )[concurrency](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency) in the workflow. Since this is not the case I would also presume this is an issue with your self-hosted runner.